# Flask: Submit a form using a slider

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

In flask, how can I create a 'slide to submit' like this?

1. https://codepen.io/BoringCode/pen/FfzLs
2. https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Submit-A-Form-By-Sliding-slide-to-submit.html

I added

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

in my `<head>` tag in `base.html` and used the jquery from above fiddles to make it work. Funny thing is, this works -

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<script>
 
        $(".slide-submit button").html("test"); //test

</script>
```

but this doesn't

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<script>
 
        $(".slide-submit button").draggable();

</script>
```

Comment: is there any help here?

Comment: Did you include the plugin you mention in point #2?

Comment: can you show us the HTML code concerned?

Comment: @0stone0 yes, i did

Comment: @GeomanYabes - which file would you like to see? It is huge and might be irrelevant, most of it,

Comment: The form where you put the slider and the slider itself. You can omit parts not related to the slider, i.e., `input` elements inside the form. Primarily interested in `.slide-submit button`

Answer (score 0):

Your console errors are not known for instance, so I assume that you are using the draggable function incorrectly

According to the documentation of [this](https://codepen.io/BoringCode/pen/FfzLs) code pen link (mentioned by you) the correct way to use the function is following

```
$(".slide-submit button").draggable({
    cancel: false,
    containment: "parent",
    axis: "x", 
    stop: function() 
    {
        //this segment is optional replace with your own instructions
        //the condition is used to check if sliding was done till end
        if (($(this).parent().width() / 2) === ($(this).position().left + 8))
        {
            $(this).css({left: "auto", right: 0})
            .addClass("submitted") //to change UI design to something else
            .text("Submitting...") // to tell user be patience data is being sent
            .draggable('false'); // disable dragging while sending operation
            $(this).closest("form").submit(); //actually submit the form
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(this).css({left: 0});
            //if sliding was stoped by user but it was not near the end then reset position of slider to the start
        }
    }}).on("click", function() 
    {
        return false;
    });
```

where following things are being set in the above function and are mandatory otherwise you won't be able to use the button on slide event

- Set Property if it can be Cancelable
- Set the axis of drag e.g. X or Y
- A function to tell that the dragging or sliding has been stopped by user (important)
- A click function to call on first interaction and cancel default behavior of button